# Is it possible to add domains like www.yourdomain.com into AMP Iframe?

Tags: amp-html

I want to show a iframe on AMP page. Is it possible to add domains like *www.yourdomain.com* into AMP Iframe?

```
<amp-iframe width="200" height="100"
    sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"
    layout="responsive"
    frameborder="0"
    src="http:www.mydomain.com">
</amp-iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we can add domain like that as shown example below

```
<amp-iframe width="600" height="400" layout="responsive" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups" frameborder="0"   src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=place_id:ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA&key=AIzaSyCNCZ0Twm_HFRaZ5i-FuPDYs3rLwm4_848"></amp-iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks Ghanshyam. But this code for showing Google MAP. Actually i wanna add ANOTHER WEBSITE. is that possible?

Comment: Yes send me URL or replace "src" with your URL will show your URL

Comment: <amp-iframe width="200" height="100" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" layout="responsive" frameborder="0" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Traffic"></amp-iframe>

Comment: Working for you mate ?

Comment: But its not working here: https://ampbyexample.com/playground/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fampbyexample.com%2Fcomponents%2Famp-iframe%2Fsource%2F

Comment: <amp-iframe width="200" height="100"
    sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"
    layout="responsive"
    frameborder="0"
    src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Traffic">
</amp-iframe>

Comment: I have tried and working fine with shared code mate.

Copy the whole code and paste it where you need that. it will open your URL to load.

Comment: Thankyou so much!

Answer (score 1):

Keep care. The iframe site MUST be a **https://** site.

Comment: Than you so much! It save my day.